# How to customize different TensorFlow-Federated functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow-federated

I have read and studied the TFF [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_2) and [APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff) pages precisely. But I am confused about the usage of the functions and how to control them.

For example, in tutorials, there is a function that is responsible for aggregating metrics.

```py
     @tff.federated_computation
     def aggregate_mnist_metrics_across_clients(metrics):
       return {
       'num_examples': tff.federated_sum(metrics.num_examples),
       'loss': tff.federated_mean(metrics.loss, metrics.num_examples),
       'accuracy':tff.federated_mean(metrics.accuracy,metrics.num_examples)
    }
```

It is called in the **MODEL** class. But I need to have access to the elements of the metric after it is called in the class. I want to modify the metrics after it is called in the model and call them in other functions.
 
However, for example, I can not call them (e.g. with `tff.Type` such as `.type_signature`, since it needs namedTuple for `__getattr__`). And I did not understand the total intuitive behind the concept of how they can be used in other function's bodies of the code?
In TFF, I expect every function has a placement in either the server or clients side, but both of them can be accessible in any function which makes it confusing. **Who is responsible for calculating?** @CLIENT or @SERVER? 
 
could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one misconception is that `tff.learning.Model` is the interface used by the `tff.learning` module and is *not required* if not any module methods such as `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process()`. Currently the federated averaging implementation does not have a hook to modify the metrics post aggregation but before returning from the computation.

I highly recommend looking [Custom Federated Algorithms, Part 2: Implementing Federated Averaging](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_2), which steps through how to implement Federated Averaging without using `tff.learning`, which would allow extending the computations in any direction desired.

Additional clarification:

`aggregate_mnist_metrics_across_clients` is being returned in the [`tff.learning.Model.federated_output_computation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model#federated_output_computation) method of `class MnistModel`, a few cells down in the tutorial. The `metrics` parameter is the return value of [`tff.learning.Model.report_local_outputs()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model#report_local_outputs). Both of these methods are interfaces that need to be implemented for the `tff.learning` module methods (e.g. `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process()`) to connect up the computation in the correct way.

> In TFF, I expect every function has a placement in either the server or clients side, but both of them can be accessible in any function which makes it confusing.

In TFF the *data* has placement, not the *computations*. Computations that accept unplaced values can be used on placed values using TFF *intrinsics* (e.g. `tff.federated_mean()`, or `tff.federated_map()`). Also, a TFF computation may accept value placed at `CLIENTS` or `SERVER` and also return values placed at either.

If you haven't already, I'd highly recommend looking at the two part tutorial Custom Federated Algorithms. It spends time introducing the programming and execution model of TFF:

- [Part 1: Introduction to the Federated Core](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_1)
- [Part 2: Implementing Federated Averaging](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/custom_federated_algorithms_2)

Comment: Dear @ZacharyGarrett, I edit the question, could you have a look at it? thanks in advance.